# psake error code management

Tags: powershell, psake

I have a task running a mercurial command that fails because mercurial is not returning 0 but 1.

When mercurial returns 1 does not mean it's an error but there is nothing to do.
According to the documentation:

```
Returns 0 if push was successful, 1 if nothing to push.
```

How can I handle the return in my task so when the hg command returns 0 or 1 it won't break.

Here is the failing function

```
Function Invoke-HgBookmark([string]$bookmarkname)
{
    $repo = GetCredentials
    & $hg.file bookmark -f $bookmarkname
    Invoke-Expression "$($hg.file) push -B $bookmarkname $repo"
    if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0 -Or $LASTEXITCODE -eq 1)
    {
        return 0
    }
    else
    {
        return -1
    }
}
```

Psake is calling my function with this code:

```
try {
    $global:lastexitcode = 0                 
    & $cmd
   if ($lastexitcode -ne 0) {
        throw ("Exec: " + $errorMessage)
    }
    break
}
```

Comment: It looks like your function is trying to handle the exit code of 1.  Is the function returning `-1` or failing in some other way?  If it is returning `-1` - stick in a `Write-Host "$LastExitCode"` to see what exit code you are getting.  Your `if` expression logic looks good. BTW what's with the Invoke-Expression? I don't see why you can't invoke $hg.file like you do in the line above the iex.

Comment: Actually, I'm learning powershell... I don't need iex. Back to my problem I added the code psake is using and I can't overwrite the $lastexitcode in case hg returns 1

Comment: Ah, in that case try replacing `Return x` with `$LastExitCode = x`.

Comment: $LastExitCode does not work, $global:lastexitcode = 0 is working fine. Not very sure why... I will try to dig a little bit and write a decent answer

Comment: Yeah that makes sense.  When you set $LastExitCode in your script it modifies the value for the scope of the function where it is set.  So yeah, I should have said to use `$global:LastExitCode = x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the function, set `$global:LastExitCode` to the desired value before it exits.  You have to use the `global:` prefix in order to modify the global variable.  Otherwise PowerShell does a "copy-on-write" operation and modifies a variable with the same name that is local to the function.